# Change barcode lookup from sheet to workbook

Tags: excel, vba, lookup, barcode

I have a workbook that has 4 different sheets for inventory purposes (each sheet corresponds to a type of inventory to make organizing easier). Not the best setup, but I have a barcode lookup system where I scan the item's barcode and Excel finds and highlights the corresponding row (containing info like name, picture, quantity, etc.) that's all updated manually. Originally everything was on one sheet but recently I have sorted them out into 4 different sheets. Since then the barcode lookup only works on the original inventory sheet (makes sense since the code was only for that one sheet). I have been unable to figure out how to change the code to work on the whole workbook. I have tried to change worksheet to workbook (didn't work), then I tried to add a `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("")` for each sheet (also didn't work) and a handful of other changes. If anyone has any idea on how to change it so it searches the workbook instead of the one sheet I would appreciate it.
Here is a copy of the working code for the first sheet:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory List")

 Dim rangeToLook As Range
 Set rangeToLook = ws.Range("C3:C1000")

 Dim wholeRange As Range
 Set wholeRange = rangeToLook.Resize(, 10)

 ' change 14408667 to yours grey color code here
 wholeRange.Cells.Interior.Color = 14408667

 Dim code As Variant
     code = InputBox("Please scan a barcode and hit enter if you need to")

 Dim matchedCell As Range
 Set matchedCell = rangeToLook.Find(what:=code, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                   lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)

     If Not matchedCell Is Nothing Then
         With matchedCell
             Application.Goto .Cells(1)
             .Resize(1, 10).Interior.ColorIndex = 20
         End With
     Else
         MsgBox "Barcode Not Found"
     End If

 End Sub
```

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: Do you want the code to works for **all existing sheets**, or to run on any (chosen) sheet? I mean to iterate between all existing sheets and run for each of them or to offer the possibility to choose a sheet?

Comment: Yes, I want it to work for all existing sheets. So the button to input the barcode scan is on the first sheet but I want it to find the item even if it is on the 4th sheet by itself, I don't want to go sheet by sheet inputting the barcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim rangeToLook As Range
 Dim wholeRange As Range
 Dim code As Variant
 Dim matchedCell As Range
 
 code = InputBox("Please scan a barcode and hit enter if you need to")
 
 For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Set rangeToLook = ws.Range("C3:C1000")
    Set wholeRange = rangeToLook.Resize(, 10)

    wholeRange.Interior.Color = 14408667

    Set matchedCell = rangeToLook.Find(what:=code, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                   lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)

    If Not matchedCell Is Nothing Then
        With matchedCell
            Application.Goto .Cells(1)
            .Resize(1, 10).Interior.ColorIndex = 20
            Exit For
        End With
    End If
 Next
 
 If matchedCell Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Barcode Not Found"
 End If
 
 End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this and unfortunately, it didn't work at all... it asked me to input a barcode, I did, and then it went and asked another 4 times (once per sheet without letting me stop the process) while selecting and highlighting empty cells on each page and not the one item I was looking for.

Comment: This one looks like it works great. The only question I have left is that after finding the item (it does find it and pick the correct cell), I'm always getting the pop-up for barcode not found (even though it did find it). I don't see anything in the code from what I understand of it that would make it do that.

Comment: You understand this more than I do, so I'm beyond lost on this one. It doesn't look like anything should cause it.. It happened every single time, it might be that another code I have is causing an issue (I have another code that moves selected items to the bottom of the list if it is discontinued and another one to automatically resize the photos to fit in the cells). I'll have to play around with it a bit and I'll leave any updates if I get anywhere.

Comment: @intheend555 - please try the updated version. I added 2 lines. which essentially check the same thing, but differently. Maybe this will help.

Comment: @intheend555  When the `intheend555` is not Nothing, you  must add `Exit For, or event `Exit Sub` after the line `.Resize(1, 10).Interior.ColorIndex = 20`. Otherwise, the code reaches the part with the message box (if in another sheet it did not find anything...).

Comment: The codes all work standalone with their own buttons, but I did just notice one thing. The barcode button flashes and turns a lighter shade when I scroll in the sheet it's on (I have it anchored/locked to the top of the first sheet), and the other two buttons don't do that.

Comment: @ZygD the new code didn't fix it so I changed it back to the other one you put up and I inserted `Exit For` right after `.Resize(1, 10).Interior.ColorIndex = 20`  like @ FaneDuru posted and it looks like it now runs without any problems.